# Trouble adding st_point column with activerecord-postgis-adapter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, postgis

This is a pretty verbatim copy of what I wrote on the [project github](https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter/issues/214). Forgive me for cross posting but I was hoping someone here had come across this error:

```
undefined method `st_point' for #
<ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQL::TableDefinition:0x0055cdd8f278e8>
```

This is my Gemfile lock:

```
activerecord (4.2.7.1)
activerecord-postgis-adapter (3.1.4)
```

and the migration:

```
class CreateLocations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    enable_extension "postgis"
    create_table :locations do |t|
      t.st_point :geom, geographic: true, srid: 4326, dimension: 2
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

What's wierd is that this works in development mode. It's just when I run the migrations for the test environment that it fails.

After `rake db:create RAILS_ENV=test`, I have conntected to the test database with `psql` and run `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`.

**tl;dr**

`t.st_point` in the migration is undefined, only in the test environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error was "postgres" instead of "postgis" in the ENV["DATABASE_URL"]

That it what others suggested on the thread. I was being stubborn by not checking for this, but it turns out to be the correct cause.